gdebi is not looking for local files
I am trying to make custom jammy ISO, and in the late_command, I am running a script to use gdebi and install my custom packages from the mounted cdrom /media/cdrom/pool/extras but its not working! I see that gdebi tries to connect to archive.ubuntu.com and fails, all the required packages are available locally on the mount!
I have installed
gdebi-core
version
gdebi 0.9.5.7+nmu6
This used to work earlier, with older versions
I even tried adding this entry to  /etc/apt/sources.list:
deb [trusted=yes] file:/media/cdrom/pool/extras jammy main restricted

didn't help!
what should I do to make gdebi search locally!?

iirc the URI should point to the root of the distro (perhaps just file:/media/cdrom in your case?)

@steeldriver Thanks, tried it but doesn't help! :(
